# EF4 code-first: defining object relationships, foreign keys

Tags: .net, entity-framework, mapping, entity-relationship, code-first

**< RANT_MODE >**

*EF code-first approach is meant to save lots of time but for the time being I've only seen toy examples and spent hours trying to understand how I can make it generate the db I want. But still hoping that Eureka moment :-)*

**< RANT_MODE />**

On to the questions!

### Virtual vs. concrete properties

I'm trying to understand how EF maps and retrieves object relationships. When should I mark a property as `virtual` and when not? (As in `public Person Owner { get; set; }` vs. `public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }`.) In the dozens of examples of code-first I've seen they seem to use these interchangably, without much in terms of explanation. What I do know is that navigation properties (`public virtual ICollection<Person> Owners { get; set; }`) need to be `virtual` in order to make lazy loading possible (correct..?), but how does that apply in the world of non-collections?

### Object relationships and foreign keys

I wasn't able to find any information on whether I should include a foreign key field (`public int OwnerId { get; set; }`) in addition to the 'main' property I'm interested in (`public Person Owner { get; set; }`). I tried not to, and EF kindly auto-added an int column named `Owner_Id` in my table, seemingly understanding what I meant to achieve.

In [Conventions for Code First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/conventions-for-code-first) (section 'Foreign Keys') the EF Team mention that "it is common to include a foreign key property on the dependent end of a relationship", and that "Code First will now infer that any property named '' (i.e. OwnerId) [...] with the same data type as the primary key, represents a foreign key for the relationship". Ie. if I have both EF will know they're related.

But is it considered good practice to explicitly specify such properties holding FKs, in addition to 'foreign objects' themselves?

### Foreign objects, foreign keys - continued

As I mentioned above, even if I only have `public Person Owner { get; set; }` in my object (say `Event`), the table `Events` will feature an `Owner_Id` column automagically added by EF. What's more, upon retrieval I will have access to properties of `Owner`.

However, consider the following scenario. I've got two classes:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public class OpenIdAccount : Account
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

I want them to be TPT-related. This means manual mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().MapHierarchy(a => new
{
    a.Id, 
    Owner_Id = a.Owner.Id
}).ToTable("Account");

modelBuilder.Entity<OpenIdAccount>().MapHierarchy(a => new
{
    a.Id,
    a.Identifier
}).ToTable("OpenIdAccount");
```

As you may notice, I tried to recreate what EF does with my `Owner_Id` column. Yet upon retrieval, `myAccountInstanceFromDb.Owner` is null. Why is that? How do I tell EF that it should do its magic and populate my `Owner` property?

### Pointers, pointers

I will be most grateful if you could clarify the above - got to the point of really wishing to know the answers, but being unable to read yet another article that merely showcases another toy example of how easy it is to play with EF. That said, if you do have an in-depth up-to-date reference on EF's brains, please do post links too.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Code first is designed to save you time if you aren't too concerned with the database. If you want minute control then the best route is to create it in SQL Management Studio and use database first to generate your EDMX.

Comment: Guess it depends on one's view on what's "minute control" :-) Personally I don't care about column order and column names, but I do want a database that's efficient and well designed from an engineering point of view... one that I wouldn't be terrified to work with in the future if I eg. need to query it directly. But your point is definitely valid and I agree - CF provides us with powerful tools but also takes some control away.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once, particularly the rant.  I'm not sure how code by convention is suppose operate if in fact the conventions are not published in any referenceable way.  I little convention trick here, and another one there. Very painful.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, thou I have to say that thanks to some helpful people here at SO I think I've been though the worst, and starting to actually enjoy EF4. The point on conventions being explained in full someplace is still valid thou, most of what I now know is pieces from various ScottGu's posts and other blogs painfully brought together by trial-and-errror. Hopefully things will improve a lot when it goes into RTM!

Comment: Loved this post. I agree with you all, I just started my path this week on EF4 + SQL CE4 and have seen every painful step you describe here, there is not single post that gives you a broad pictures, just lot of similar toy samples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Virtual vs. Final properties:

This has really nothing to do with code first, it's the topic of EF and POCOs: When you have POCOs you lose a bunch of EF supports for your navigation properties and you can opt in to them by making them virtual. This lets EF to make a proxy at runtime and give you the support by overriding the nav properties in that proxy class. Those supports are *Change Notification*, *Relationship Fixup* and *Lazy Loading*.

Lazy Loading works the same for Collection and non Collection type navigation properties. Also it's considered to be a *good practice* to always mark your navigation properties as virtual.

#### Foreign Key Association or Independent Associations

EF3.5 does not support FKs in the associations and makes them hidden (a.k.a *Independent Associations*). EF4 starts to support FKs in the associations (a.k.a *Foreign Key Association*). Depend on which one you like, you can explicitly include or not include FK properties, but it's definitely a good practice to explicitly specify FK properties, in addition to navigation properties since it gives you ultimate flexibility to work with your objects.

> Upon retrieval, myAccountInstanceFromDb.Owner is null. Why is that? How do I tell EF that it should do its magic and populate my Owner property?

Of course, you didn't marked it as virtual so Lazy Loading is not supported yet you did not explicitly eager load or defer load it as well. To resolve that either use *virtual* keyword and let EF lazy load it for you or use *Include* method to eager load it at the time the whole object is materialized.

#### Scalar properties vs. Navigation properties

*Scalar properties* are properties whose values are literally contained in the entity and correspond with the table columns (e.g. Account.Id). 

*Navigation properties* are merely *pointers* to the related entities. For example the Account entity has an Owner property that will enable the application to navigate from an Account to the Owner that owns that Account. 

So, back to your question, all you need to do is to specify a navigation property as `virtual Person Owner` and *optionally* specify a FK property as `int OwnerId` and you are good to go.

Comment: @Morteza, thanks for your time answering my basic questions again - you truly are a champion of knowledge! "It's considered to be a good practice to always mark your navigation properties as virtual" - having read your explanation I understand that now. The question is what's the difference between a plain property and a navigation property - is it enough to just have a navigation property in an object or does it need to be backed up by a plain property?

Comment: In other words, if I have an `Account` that belongs to a `Person`, in order to define the relationship between them do I: 1) specify a _property_ `int OwnerId` and a _navigation property_ `virtual Person Owner`, or 2) specify a _property_ `Person Owner`, or 3) specify a _navigation property_ `virtual Person Owner`?

Comment: PS: I have read [an explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx) but I'm still not sure if a navigation property can stand all on its own or if it needs support from an explicit property either referring to the other object itself / its FK.

Comment: No problem and Thanks :) 

Yes, a navigation property can stand all on its own, please see my updated answer on this topic.

Comment: @Morteza, you saved the day again. When you talk _pointers_ to me, the world suddenly becomes that much more clear and understandable. I could only wish at least some articles on EF followed your way of explaining things. Topic closed from my point of view - see you on the next one :-)

Comment: Wow, that was very flattering, thank you! I'm happy it helped and yep, see you on the next one dude :)

Answer (score 0):

marking a property virtual makes the related objects to be lazy invoked

you need not add a foreign key field
public Person Owner { get; set; } will add a foreign key mapping

Comment: Thanks for confirming that! However, as you may see from `.MapHierarchy` I need to do this manually because I'm using TPT strategy.